# How to make fetch size work in OpenSearch SQL plug-in?

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, opensearch

OpenSearch documentation says that `fetch_size` is supported and should work. However, this definitely is not working for me in OpenSearch 2.5.3.

**Query 1:**

```
POST _plugins/_sql/
{
  "query" : "SELECT start_time FROM my_opensearch_index"
}
```

**Response 1:**

```
{
  "schema": [
    {
      "name": "start_time",
      "type": "timestamp"
    }
  ],
  "datarows": [
    [
      "2022-12-01 02:46:18.406516529"
    ],
    [
      "2022-12-01 02:46:15.83386667"
    ],
...
],
    [
      "2022-12-01 02:57:49.658765135"
    ]
  ],
  "total": 200,
  "size": 200,
  "status": 200
}
```

`200` seems to be the default `size` for a `SQL` query. However, when I try this query:

**Query 2:**

```
POST _plugins/_sql/
{
  "fetch_size" : 5,
  "query" : "SELECT start_time FROM my_opensearch_index"
}
```

**Response 2:**

```
{
  "error": {
    "reason": "There was internal problem at backend",
    "details": "Index type [my_opensearch_index] does not exist",
    "type": "IllegalArgumentException"
  },
  "status": 500
}
```

Note that the only thing that changed in the `Query 2` is the addition of `"fetch_size" : 5,` to the query.

NOTE: This was done on OpenSearch 2.5.3; I haven't tried this on ElasticSearch and I know they have a similar feature.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your error with opensearch 2.6.0, `fetch_size` works as expected. Your error indicates that the index doesn't exist -> if, after sending the request that got you the error response, remove the fetch_size property again, do you get a 200? Also, do you have the same issue with other indices? If yes to all the questions above, it seems like a bug to me, which they may have solved with v2.6.0

Comment: @glenacota did you try it on ElasticSearch or OpenSearch? I'm seeing the issue on OpenSearch

Comment: opensearch 2.6.0

Comment: @glenacota I'm assuming you used an actual index instead of an index-alias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using index name in the `FROM` clause instead of an index alias.

Index aliases [are not handled](https://github.com/opensearch-project/sql/issues/1398) correctly in this case.

Comment: So, I have multiple shards of the same index `index-001`, `index-002`, etc. The `alias` `index` basically groups these shards together. Is there a good way to specify all the shards in the `FROM` section? I tried this and didn't work `SELECT * FROM index-*`, which works if you don't pass `fetch_data`, or `filter` in the request.

Answer (score 0):

it works for csv and json formats, as I run it on aws open search
endpoint

POST https://..../_plugins/_sql?format=csv' or _plugins/_sql?format=json

```
'{
   "fetch_size":500,
  "query": "SELECT some FROM other LIMIT 500"
}'
```